# How to install mbed CLI on a Windows 10 system with Python 3.5?

Tags: python, mbed

I would like to install the ARM mbed CLI on my PC. I follow this tutorial from the official website:
https://docs.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os-handbook/en/5.1/dev_tools/cli/

One of the prerequisites is having Python installed on the system. The tutorial mentions:

> **Python -** mbed CLI is a Python script, so you’ll need Python in order to use it. mbed CLI was tested with version 2.7.9 of Python. You can download that or a newer version here.

I do have Python installed, but not the 2.7 version. I have `Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)` instead.
The next prerequisite is having **Git** and **Mercurial** installed. The tutorial mentions:

> **Git and Mercurial -** mbed CLI supports both Git and Mercurial repositories, so you’ll need to install both.
>   *Note: The directories of Git and Mercurial executables (git and hg) need to be in your system’s PATH.*

I installed both:

```
> git --version
git version 2.10.2.windows.1

> hg --version
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 4.0)
```

I install mbed CLI like this:

```
> pip install mbed-cli
Collecting mbed-cli
Installing collected packages: mbed-cli
Successfully installed mbed-cli-0.9.10
```

But it turns out that the installation is not good. The windows command line doesn't recognize mbed commands:

```
> mbed --help
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\mbed.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mbed\mbed.py", line 989
    sorted_scms = sorted(sorted_scms, key=lambda (m, _): not m)
                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I suspect that the Python 3.5 version is to blame (perhaps it would work with Python 2.7, I don't know). Is there a way to make it work with Python 3.5? PS: I don't like to install Python 2.7 side-by-side with my existing Python 3.5. That's too much hassle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mbed CLI requires python 2.7.* . Python 3.* is not supported yet.

Comment: Thank you sir. So my only option is to install python 2.7 next to python 3.5 - side by side?

Comment: Yes, that shouldnt be an issue though as they fundamentally have different binaries that they run from. The only problem you may have is what `python` is aliased to. By installing pythong 2.7 second it will most likely override `python` and alias it to python27.exe instead of python3.exe.